# Save several .ts files in one container, while preserving direct http access

Tags: http, video, ffmpeg, ftp, mp4

For HLS-video-streaming I have several .ts files and a .m3u8 playlist-file on my ftp-server. The .m3u8 file links relative to these .ts files. Because I'm now implementing a more advanced data management on distributed servers and a hashed folder structure, it would be most convinient if these .ts files would stay at the same place in one kind of "container"(e.g. .mp4?).

Is there a way to save several .ts files in another file structure which is then still accessible for the video player directly via http? E.g. http://example.com/container.mp4:video1.ts and the next .ts file like http://example.com/container.mp4:video2.ts ?

Obviously this access should be possible without loading/unpacking the whole "container". Furthermore it would be even more convinient, if the .m3u8 file would be saved in this "container" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS is a container, just like MP4. But unlike MP4 you can simply concatenate the files then update the m3u8 with the offsets of each segment. No. You can not put the m3u8 inside. If you want 1 file = 1 video, just use MP4.